# How to map a list of string to emptylists?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a set of String and want to map each of them to an empty list then return. I know a for loop could solve it, but is there a good way to do it with Java Stream?

e.g: I have a Set of `{"a", "b", "c"}`

and I want to return a map `Map<String, List<Object>>` to be something like `{"a": emptyList(), "b": emptyList(), "c": emptyList()}`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) for this purpose.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = strings.stream()
    .collect(toMap(identity(), e -> new ArrayList<>()));
```

(*where [identity()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) is also statically imported*).

Given your question, you may also be interested in [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), which allows you to do the initialization lazily.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
List<Object> listForA = result.computeIfAbsent("a", e -> new ArrayList<>());
// result = {a=[]}
```

Comment: I would prefer `.collect(toMap(identity(), e -> new ArrayList<>()))` here.